# How to pass resources to view?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am newbie in laravel. I want to know how can I pass the data result from the resource collection to view. I saw in tutorial if I have not uses resource then I can simply return like this to view.

```
return view('articles.index')->with('posts', $posts);
```

I was practicing using resource collection, I am not sure how to return to view.

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::all();
    return ArticleResource::collection($articles);
}
```

I have tried using following which returns data to the view but I am not being able to show that data.

```
return view('articles.index')->with('articles', ArticleResource::collection($articles));
```

Comment: Do you want to pass `ArticleResource::collection($articles);` to view?

Comment: @LeenaPatel I dont know how how to pass it to view

Comment: did you tried `return new ArticleResource($articles); ` ?

Comment: Yes but how can I render this return to articles.index view??

Comment: check my answer @user1687891

Answer (score 4):

```
'article' => (new ArticleResource($article))->resolve(),
```

Consider that this way it become an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Resource Collection by creating its object.

```
$data = [ 
    'articles' => new ArticleResource::collection($articles)
]

return view('articles.index')->with('data', $data);
```

and in your blade use it like

```
{{ json_encode($articles) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your **Resource Response(Collection)** on **`blade` view** page. like this way.

> **On Controller**

```
 $data  =  User::where('id',Auth::id())->first();
 $resumeReso  = new  ResumeViewAllRes($data);
 return view("Resume.viewAll")->with(['data'=>(object)$resumeReso->toArray($request)]);
```

I used **Array** on `With()`  because maybe future i have to pass more data.
your **Resource File** will be old as we used for **`Collection`**. so that i did not mention that code here.

So after this, you can easily access any variable as **`Object`** in **Blade** File.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = ArticleResource::collection($articles);
    
    return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

Then in your blade you can use the articles variable like this

```
@foreach(json_decode(json_encode($files)) as $article)
   // $article->data_here;
@endforeach
```